# Find function in HIVE

Tags: find, hive

I want to check if a field contains a string.

I want a function that would look like this:

```
FIND("string_to_find",field_to_search)
```

My data looks like this:

```
field_to_search
---------------
"no match in this string"
"record 2 has no matches"
"ahh finally xxxstring_to_findxxx is here"
```

I am looking for a function that identifies that the specified string is contained and at what position the string starts.

```
return
------
-1
-1
15
```

Comment: "Seek and yee shall find" - what about googling `hive string functions site:apache.org`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The built in `locate` function does nearly exactly what you need except that for your input, it would return

```
return
------
0
0
16
```

Since it indexes from 1. So all you need to do is:

```
Select locate("string_to_find","ahh finally xxxstring_to_findxxx is here") -1; --returns 15
Select locate("string_to_find","foo") -1; --returns -1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is can be achieved by using **instr** and **if** in hive.

```
select if(instr(line,"xxxstring_to_findxxx")==0,-1,instr(line,"xxxstring_to_findxxx")) as position from find_tbl;
```

where line is your column name