# Hive query to iterate and search the element

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the below tables X and y table:

```
X table 

column : Address
values : "ABCDHongKidoJapan589068".
```

I will be having 100 records like this

```
Y table

column :Name
Values :Hong
        Timm
        Agent
        Lane.
```

I want to search if any of the Y values present in X, if present that values of Y will be stored in a different column name as `Addr_nm` in X table.

Can we achieve this in Hive. ?

I tried in python, but I have the requirement to do in the hive.

Comment: Please share schema for tables X and Y.

Comment: @vikrantrana : thanks for your reply. PFB schema:  Table X  has two columns ---  (id and Address) . Table Y has one column  --- (Name) . All the columns are of data type string

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926318/find-function-in-hive

Comment: also look some methods using regex also.